# Trying to verify passwords are matching using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that is supposed to register a user and I have two inputs for passwords that are supposed to be the same. I use html for the form and javascript to check if both inputs are matching. The code I'm using doesn't work though because even if the passwords are different, the user data is still sent to my console when the form shouldn't be able to submit in the first place. These are portions of my html file.

```
<form id="registration-info" method="POST" action="/registration" onsubmit="return validatePassword();">
```

....

```
<div class="mb-3">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
           Please enter a password.
      </div>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
       <label for="repeat_password">Repeat Password</label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" name="repeat_password" id="repeat_password"required>

       <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
            var password = document.getElementById("password")
                , repeat_password = document.getElementById("repeat_password");

            function validatePassword(){
                 if(password.value != repeat_password.value) {
                       document.repeat_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
                 } else {
                       document.repeat_password.setCustomValidity('');
                 }
            }
      </script>
</div>
```

Comment: @Etom, use the var `repeat_password` instead of `document.repeat_password`. `id`'s are registered on the `window` object, not `document`. And I don't see `validatePassword()` used anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Doh, someone didn't have enough coffee today :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes there you'll need to fix up.

## Use a JavaScript event listener and remove `document.`.

```
form = document.getElementById("registration-info");
form.onclick = function() {
     var password = document.getElementById("password");
     var repeat_password = document.getElementById("repeat_password");

     if(password.value != repeat_password.value) {
          repeat_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
     } else {
          document.repeat_password.setCustomValidity('');
     }
}
```

You do not need to use `document.` when references variables you have set. Using a JavaScript event listener helps you write clean code, that separates UI and logic.